# Let $X$ be a non-empty set of ordinals. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $X$ to be an ordinal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> $X$ is ordinal if and only if X is transitive and well-ordered under $\in$.

Let $X$ be a non-empty set of ordinals. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for $X$ to be an ordinal?

---

I found that the answer is quite simple in case $X$ is finite.

> Assume $X$ has $n$ elements $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$. First of all, $X$ is well-ordered under $\in$, so WLOG we can safely assume that $a_1\in a_2\in a_3\in\cdots\in a_n$, hence $a_i\in a_n$ for all $0<i<n$. It is easily to prove that $a_1=\emptyset$. As a result, $X$ is ordinal $\implies$ $\emptyset\in X$ and $\exists c\in X,X\setminus\{c\}\subsetneq c$. One can easily verify that $\emptyset\in X$ and $\exists c\in X,X\setminus\{c\}\subsetneq c\implies X$ is ordinal.

Please help me in case $X$ is infinite!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $X$ of ordinals is itself an ordinal if and only if $X$ is transitive, i.e. every element of $X$ is a subset of $X$.

Since, for every ordinal $\alpha$, $\alpha$ is transitive this is clearly necessary.

But it is also sufficient: A set $Y$ is an ordinal iff it is transitive an strictly totally ordered by $\in$. Since $X$ is a set of ordinals, it is strictly totally ordered by $\in$ and by our requirement it is transitive as well.

Comment: Hi @Mesken, What do you mean when you wrote $(X; \in)$? It is a well-ordered set or just partially ordered?

Comment: @LEANHDUNG I actually shouldn't have written that, since it's misleading. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: You meant that any set of ordinals is strictly totally ordered by $\in$. That is for any ordinals $a$ and $b$, either $a\in b$ or $b\in a$.

Comment: @LEANHDUNG or $a = b$, yes.

Comment: Please give me some hints to prove that.

Comment: @LEANHDUNG Let $a,b$ be ordinals and $a \subsetneq b$. Let $c = \min b \setminus a$. Prove that $a = c \in b$. Now prove that for all ordinals $a,b$ $a \subseteq b$ or $b \subseteq a$. Why? Otherwise $c = a \cap b \subsetneq a,b$ and hence $c \in a \cap b = c$ -- contradicting regularity.

Comment: Thank you so much, from your hints at another post, I have have posted it as an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845356/for-any-two-ordinals-x-and-y-either-x-in-y-or-x-y-or-y-in-x/2845669#2845669.