# Every set of ordinals is well-ordered with respect to $\in$

Tags: proof-verification, ordinals

Does my attempt look fine or contain gaps? Thank you so much!

---

> **Theorem:** Every set of ordinals is well-ordered with respect to $\in$.

---

> **Lemma 1:** Every nonempty set of ordinals has a least element with respect to $\in$.

**Proof:**

Let $X$ be a nonempty set of ordinals. Take $\alpha\in X$.

1. $\alpha \cap X=\emptyset$

Suppose that $\beta \in X$ and $\beta\neq\alpha$. I claim that $\alpha\in\beta$. If not, $\beta\in\alpha$. Moreover, $\beta\in X$. Then $\beta\in\alpha \cap X$. This is a contradiction.

Hence $\forall (\beta\in X \text{ and }\beta\neq\alpha):\alpha\in\beta$. Thus $\alpha$ is the least element of $X$.

2. $\alpha \cap X\neq\emptyset$

Then $\alpha \cap X$ is a nonempty subset of $\alpha$ and thus has a least element since $\alpha$ is well-ordered.

Let $\delta$ be the least element of $\alpha \cap X$. For all $\theta\in X$:

- $\theta\in \alpha$

Then $\theta\in \alpha \cap X$ and thus $\delta\in\theta$ since $\delta$ is the least element of $\alpha \cap X$.

- $\theta= \alpha$

Then $\delta\in\alpha \cap X=\theta\cap X$ and thus $\delta\in\theta$.

- $\alpha\in\theta$

Then $\delta\in\alpha\in\theta$ and thus $\delta\in\theta$.

Hence $\delta$ is the least element of $X$.

---

> **Lemma 2:** For any two ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Either $\alpha\in\beta$, or $\alpha=\beta$, or $\beta\in\alpha$.

**Proof:**

I presented a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2845669/368425).

---

We proceed to prove our main theorem.

Let $X$ be a nonempty set of ordinals. Then $X$ is linearly ordered by **Lemma 2**. Every nonempty subset of $X$ has a least element by **Lemma 1**. Hence $X$ is well-ordered.

Comment: Under 2)  you start with:"...Let $\delta$ be the least element of $\alpha \cap X$..." but at that stage you have not proved yet that $\alpha \cap X$ indeed has a least element. In fact you are in the middle of try to prove that sets like that have a least element. Then you cannot use it of course.

Comment: Thank you @drhab! I'm sloppy at that point. I have added to my proof that *Then $\alpha \cap X$ is a nonempty subset of $\alpha$ and thus has a least element since $\alpha$ is well-ordered*. Is it fine now?

Comment: Looks okay. A typo: you wrote $\alpha\cap A$ at a spot where you meant to write $\alpha\cap X$.

Comment: Thank you so much @drhab! I got it. I will remove that typo now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is fine. If you know that every subset of a set well-ordered by $\in$, is itself well-ordered by $\in$ then there is a fast way to prove your claim: Let $\beta =\bigcup_{\alpha\in X}(\alpha+1)$. Then $\beta $ is an ordinal and $X\subseteq \beta,\ $ which implies that $X$ is well-ordered by $\in$ since $\beta$ is.

Comment: From your definition of $\beta$, I'm unable to get why $\beta$ is an ordinal. Please elaborate more on this point!

Comment: [The union of a set of ordinals is an ordinal.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_Ordinals_is_Ordinal)